# Attempted import error : 'createLocation' is not exported from 'history' with conflicting History and React-router-dom versions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, react-router-dom

I was trying to set up an existing project in a new development server. However I get the following error:

> ./node_modules/react-router-dom/esm/react-router-dom.js
> Attempted import error : 'createLocation' is not exported from 'history'.

Searching for a solution I found that it might be because there are conflicting versions of the history and react-router-dom. It seems that react-router-dom 5.2.0 works with history 4.9.0, and I have history 5.0.0. The solution should be downgrading history to 4.9.0, but in the existing project, with the same versions, this error does not appear.

I checked the libraries versions with `npm list -depth=0`

```
├── @ant-design/compatible@1.0.8
├── @ant-design/icons@4.2.2
├── @babel/preset-env@7.11.5
├── @babel/preset-react@7.10.4
├── @craco/craco@5.7.0
├── @types/jest@26.0.14
├── @types/jwt-decode@2.2.1
├── @types/node@14.11.1
├── @types/react-dom@16.9.8
├── @types/react-highlight-words@0.16.1
├── @types/react-redux@7.1.9
├── @types/react-resizable@1.7.2
├── @types/react-router-dom@5.1.5
├── @types/react-table@7.0.23
├── @types/react@16.9.49
├── @types/redux-logger@3.0.8
├── @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@3.10.1
├── @typescript-eslint/parser@3.10.1
├── antd@4.10.2
├── axios@0.19.2
├── bootstrap@4.5.2
├── craco-less@1.17.0
├── env-cmd@10.1.0
├── eslint-plugin-react-hooks@4.1.2
├── eslint-plugin-react@7.20.6
├── eslint@6.8.0
├── history@5.0.0
├── js-file-download@0.4.12
├── jwt-decode@3.1.2
├── lodash@4.17.20
├── mocker-data-generator@2.9.0
├── moment@2.28.0
├── node-sass@4.14.1
├── password-validator@5.1.0
├── prettier@1.19.1
├── query-string@6.13.2
├── react-dom@16.13.1
├── react-highlight-words@0.16.0
├── react-redux@7.2.1
├── react-resizable@1.11.0
├── react-router-dom@5.2.0
├── react-scripts@3.4.3
├── react-test-renderer@16.13.1
├── react@16.13.1
├── redux-devtools-extension@2.13.8
├── redux-logger@3.0.6
├── redux-thunk@2.3.0
├── redux@4.0.5
├── resize-observer-polyfill@1.5.1
├── rsuite@4.8.2
├── typescript@3.9.7
├── webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2
└── webpack-hot-middleware@2.25.0
```

Ideally I wanted to use the same versions as the existing project, however I dont understand how the project is working with the conflicting versions of history and react-router-dom.

Answer (score 0):

History 5.x.x does not export `createLocation`. Therefore it will never work if you have that `history` version in your root `package.json` and trying to do that import from your project.